# html5 tags added dynamically by JQuery not styled by IE8

Tags: html, jquery, css, internet-explorer, modernizr

I have in my project some html5 tags as `header` , `footer`, etc... Some of them are added dynamically with jQuery `.clone(...)` . The problem is that IE<8 doesn't style those html5 tags added dynamically. I am using Modernizr and html5shiv but the problem still there. Does anyone know how to fix that? I've been thinking in remove all the html5 tags from my markup but I don't like the idea...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle? Or at least some code?

Comment: you shouldn't need to use both Modernizr and html5shiv because Modernizr already includes the html5shiv feature.

Comment: Right, I know, but it doesn't work with only Modernizr, as same as with both.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that your shiv code is being added after your styles. You'll need to arrange your javascript to download and execute the shiv, or Modernizer, before anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't seem to be the problem because I am adding the libraries (Modernizr and html5shiv) just after the css, in the head of the document.

Answer (score 0):

This was probably due to html5shiv not supporting html5 tags added to the document dynamically. Initially innerShiv was created to address this issue. See: [the article about inner shiv.](http://css-tricks.com/html5-innershiv/) These days this patch is already integrated to html5shiv so you may simply need to update the html5shiv library that you are using.